# Using DataReceivedHandler to open a VB form

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

My program receives data from an external device via a COM port.

I initialize the COM port connection by:

```
Public Sub InitializeReader()
   AddHandler comPort.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler
   comPort.Open()
End Sub
```

And I receive data from the device/port by:

```
Public Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
   IncomingData = comPort.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

I would like to open a windows form upon getting a chip read. However, when I do  so using the DataReceivedHandler Sub, my program stops responding.

So, something like this crashes the program:

```
Public Sub DataReceivedHandler(sender AS Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
   IncomingData = comPort.ReadLine()
   If FormOpen = False Then
       FormOpen = True
       NewForm.Visible = True
   End If
End Sub
```

If I instead change `NewForm.Visible = True` to `NewForm.ShowDialog()` it works fine. However, I need the user to interact with the new form for longer than just one event.

I've confirmed "NewForm" works just fine. There is nothing wrong with it. If I open the form elsewhere in my program (but *not* in the DataReceivedHandler sub) it works just fine.

Does anyone know why I might be running into this issue?

Comment: Your event handler runs on a threadpool thread, always poisonous to the vb.net code like this.  You must use BeginInvoke() to ensure that the form creation code runs on the UI thread.  If you can use Me.BeginInvoke() then consider Application.OpenForms(0).BeginInvoke().

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it had to deal with threading issues. I'm unable to use BeginInvoke, however, I figured out a different way to open my form on a new thread. Works great now!

Comment: Only ever create a new form on a worker thread when you know how to do [this kind](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/) of debugging to deal with the consequences.